# Bellman-Ford negative cycle predecessor does not exist

Tags: c#, graph, bellman-ford

I have implemented the Bellman-Ford algorithm to detect negative cycles in a graph. It is worth noting that each edge in the graph has an inverse, so if an edge exists that can go from `A -> B`, there also exists an edge that can go from `B -> A`.

My problem is when I am navigating the predecessor chain (stored in the dictionary `pred`). It seems that **the source vertex never has a predecessor**, so when I am looping through each vertex in the negative cycle check, an exception is thrown because `pred` never has an entry for the source vertex.

What does this mean? There seems to be a negative cycle in the graph, but if nothing precedes the source vertex, and the source vertex is "included" in the detected negative cycle, is there really a cycle to begin with?

```
private List<Vertex> BellmanFord( Vertex source )
{
  var dist = new Dictionary<Vertex, double>();
  var pred = new Dictionary<Vertex, Vertex>();

  // Initialize
  foreach( var vertex in Vertices )
    dist[ vertex ] = double.MaxValue;
  dist[ source ] = 0;

  // Relax
  foreach( var vertex in Vertices )
    foreach( var edge in Edges )
      Relax( edge, ref dist, ref pred );

  // Check for negative cycles
  foreach( var edge in Edges )
  {
    if( dist[ edge.From ] != double.MaxValue )
      if( HasCycle( edge, ref dist )
      {
        var cycle = new List<Vertex>();
        var vertex = edge.From;

        while( vertex == edge.To )
        {
          cycle.Add( vertex );
          vertex = pred[ vertex ];
        }

        cycle.Add( edge.To );
        return cycle;
      }
  }

  return new List<Vertex>(); // No cycle
}

private void Relax( Edge edge, ref Dictionary<Vertex, double> dist, ref Dictionary<Vertex,Vertex> pred )
{
  if( dist[edge.From] == double.MaxValue )
    return;

  var newDist = dist[ edge.From ] + edge.Weight;
  if( newDist < dist[ edge.To] )
  {
    dist[ edge.To ] = newDist;
    pred[ edge.To ] = edge.From;
  }
}

private bool HasCycle( Edge edge, ref Dictionary<Vertex, double> dist )
{
  return dist[edge.To] > dist[edge.From] + edge.Weight;
}
```

And for good measure, the weight of each edge is calculated as `-1 * Math.Log( value )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding, the observed behaviour does *not* indicate a bug in your implementation. The Bellman-Ford algorithm is able to conclude that there is a cycle of negative length; this does not mean that *every* cycle of negative length can be found. The [Floyd-Warshall algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) might be more suitable for that. Both algorithms solve different formulations of the problem; the first one solves the single-source shortest path problem while the second one solved the all-pairs shotest path problem.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'm not looking to find every negative cycle; any valid one will do. Would Bellman-Ford still not be able to provide this? I would think that, if the source vertex were not a part of the negative cycle, it wouldn't appear as a predecessor in the "found" cycle in the first place.